# Perl-CGI JQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, perl, cgi

Can someone help me add a JQuery datepicker widget(similar to http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline)  to the form and a loading gif on form submit?
(I don't own the below code, got it from a support forum and i'm building on top of it).
Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advcance..

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use CGI;
    use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); # Remove this in production
    use win32::OLE;

my $who;
my $runCmd;
my $retVal;
my $fileCon;
my $copyCmd;


    my $q = new CGI;
    my $statusURL;
    my $iframeCode;
    print $q->header();

    # Output stylesheet, heading etc
    output_top($q);

    if ($q->param()) {
    # Parameters are defined, therefore the form has been submitted
    display_results($q);
    output_end2($q);

    } else {
    # We're here for the first time, display the form
    output_form($q);
    output_end($q);

    }

    # Output footer and end html

    exit 0;

    #-------------------------------------------------------------

    # Outputs the start html tag, stylesheet and heading
    sub output_top {
    my ($q) = @_;
    print $q->start_html(
        -title => 'Deployment Dashboard',
        -bgcolor => 'white',
        -style => {
        -code => '
            /* Stylesheet code */
            body {
            font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
            }
            h2 {
            color: darkblue;
            border-bottom: 1pt solid;
            width: 100%;
            }
            div {
            text-align: left;
            color: steelblue;
            border-top: darkblue 1pt solid;
            margin-top: 4pt;
            }
            a {
            text-align: left;
            color: steelblue;
            }
            th {
            text-align: right;
            padding: 2pt;
            vertical-align: top;
            }
            td {
            padding: 2pt;
            vertical-align: top;
            }
            /* End Stylesheet code */
        ',
        },
    );
    print $q->h2("Deployment Dashboard");
    }

    # Outputs a footer line and end html tags
    sub output_end {
    my ($q) = @_;
    print $q->div("Gil Gbzy Ipe");
    print $q->end_html;
    }
    sub output_end2 {
    my ($q) = @_;

    print $q->end_html;
    }

    # Displays the results of the form
    sub display_results {
    my ($q) = @_;

    #print $q->param('Input_IP');

    my @values = split(' ', $q->param('Input_IP'));
    print <<END;

<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>checkpoint 1<br></td>
    <td>checkpoint 2<br></td>
    <td>checkpoint 3<br></td>
    <td>checkpoint 4<br></td>
    <td>checkpoint 5<br></td>
    <td>checkpoint 6<br></td>
    <td>checkpoint 7<br></td>
    </tr>
END


  foreach my $val (@values) {

print "    <tr>";
print "           <td>$val</td>";
print "            <td>1</td>";
print "            <td>2</td>";
print "            <td>3</td>";
print "            <td>4</td>";
print "            <td>5</td>";
print "            <td>6</td>";
print "            <td>7</td>";
print "                </tr>";

  }
print "</table>";
    }

    # Outputs a web form
    sub output_form {
    my ($q) = @_;
    print $q->start_form(
        -name => 'main',
        -method => 'POST',
    );

    print $q->start_table;

    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td('Ip Addresses:'),
      $q->td(
        $q->textarea(-name=>'Input_IP',
            -default=>'
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2',
            -rows=>5,
            -columns=>40,
        )
      )
    );

    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td($q->submit(-value => 'Submit')),
      $q->td('&nbsp;')
    );
    print $q->end_table;
    print $q->end_form;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use that code. Whatever you are trying to achieve, use one the many template systems available and then write clean Perl and clean HTML in separate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit this is not a comprehensive answer, but this is a Perl program that generates a page, which includes some fields with the JQuery datepicker implemented, I see you are using `HEREDOC` so you can just pull the scripts from google and add the `datepicker()` method on your script, since Perl and jQuery use the $ there might be conflicts, so when referring a jQuery object make sure you use `\$` or `jQuery` otherwise it will print it out as 0.

```
use CGI; ## load the cgi module
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use Cwd;
use File::Basename;
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

use Cwd            qw( abs_path );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

my $test = dirname(abs_path($0));

my $q = new CGI; ## create a CGI object
my($day, $month, $year)=(localtime)[3,4,5];
$year = ($year+1900);


print <<HTML;
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Sistema de Captura </TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/states.js" language="javascript">  </script>
 <script>
\$(document).ready(function() {

    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    \$("#dm_date").val(curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year);
    \$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    yearRange: "1901: $year ",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });

    jQuery("#dataTable").on("change","input,textarea,select",function(){        
            if (jQuery(this).val()){
                    jQuery(this).addClass('text_com');
            }else{
                    jQuery(this).removeClass('text_com');
            }   
    }); 


    jQuery("#sendForm").button().click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var errorString="";

            jQuery("#dataTable  input, #dataTable  textarea, #dataTable  select").each(function(){      
                    if(!jQuery(this).val()){
                    errorString +=  jQuery(this).prev().text().replace(":","") + "<br />";
                    }   
            });     

                    if(errorString){

                        jQuery("#listHere").empty().html(errorString);

                        jQuery( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({

                                buttons: {
                                            "Aceptar": function() {
                                                    jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                            }
                                }

                        });
                    }else{

                        var data = jQuery("#dataHolder").serialize();

                        console.log(data);

                    }

        });

});
 </script>
 <style>
 .ui-widget{font-size:12px;}
 .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    padding: 1px;
    position: relative;
}
.inner{
    font-size:9px;

}
.padder{
    padding: 3px;   
    margin-left:-6px;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="index">
<div id="departments_listing" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" >
<div class="ui-widget-header" style="font-size:12px;">Formato de captura</div>

<form id="dataHolder">
<table id="dataTable">
<tr>
<td>
<p><span class="separate" >Fecha:</span> <input type="text" name="dm_date" id="dm_date" value="" class="text text_com"  readonly /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Nombre:</span> <input type="text" name="dm_name" id="dm_name" value="" class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Apellido Paterno:</span> <input type="text" name="dm_paterno" id="dm_paterno" value=""  class="text" /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Apellido Materno:</span> <input type="text" name="dm_materno" id="dm_materno" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<div class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all padder" >
<div class="ui-widget-header inner" > Datos USA</div>
<p><span class="separate" >Direccion</span>  
<textarea name="dm_address_usa" id="dm_address_usa"  class="text"  ></textarea>
</p>
<p><span class="separate" >Ciudad:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_city" id="dm_city" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Estado:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_state" id="dm_state" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >CP:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_zip" id="dm_zip" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Telefono:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_tel" id="dm_tel" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
</div>

<p><span class="separate" >Nombre del Padre:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_father" id="dm_father" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Nombre de la Madre:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_mother" id="dm_mother" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Fecha de Nacimiento:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_dob" id="dm_dob" value=""  class="text datepicker"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Lugar de Nacimiento:</span>  <input type="text" name="db_pob" id="db_pob" value=""  class="text"  /></p>     
</td>



<td class="moreleft">


<p><span class="separate" >Fecha de Registro:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_dor" id="dm_dor" value=""  class="text datepicker"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Lugar de Registro:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_por" id="dm_por" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Estado MX:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_state_mx" id="dm_state_mx" value=""  class="text"  /></p>

<p><span class="separate" >No. de Oficialia:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_oficialia" id="dm_oficialia" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >No. de Libro:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_book" id="dm_book" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >No. de Foja:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_foja" id="dm_foja" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >No. de Acta:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_acta" id="dm_acta" value=""  class="text"  /></p>


<p><span class="separate" >Tipo de Documento:</span>  
<select name="dm_type" id="dm_type"    class="text" >
<option value="">Selecciona</option>
<option value="Aclaracion de Acta"> Aclaración de Acta </option>
<option value="Inscripcion en el Registro Civil"> Inscripción en el Registro Civil </option>
<option value="Acta de Matrimonio"> Acta de Matrimonio </option>
<option value="Acta de Divorcio"> Acta de Divorcio </option>
<option value="Acta de Defuncion"> Acta de Defunción </option>
<option value="Registro Extemporaneo."> Registro Extemporáneo </option>
<option value="Juicios Administrativos"> Juicios Administrativos </option>
<option value="Nulidad de Acta en el Registro Civil Mexicano"> Nulidad de Acta en el Registro Civil Mexicano </option>
<option value="Apostille"> Apostille </option>
<option value="Legalización de documentos"> Legalización de documentos</option>
</select>
</p>


<p><span class="separate" >Estatus:</span>  
<select name="dm_status" id="dm_status"    class="text" >
<option value="">Selecciona</option>
<option value="Pendiente"> Pendiente </option>
<option value="Deposito en Proceso"> Deposito en Proceso </option>
<option value="Deposito Recibido"> Deposito Recibido </option>
<option value="Cerrado"> Cerrado </option>
<option value="Cancelado"> Cancelado </option>
</select> 

</p> 
<p><span class="separate" >Email:</span>  <input type="text" name="dm_email" id="dm_email" value=""  class="text"  /></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Caso :</span>  
<select name="dm_special" id="dm_special"    class="text" >
<option value="">Selecciona</option>
<option value="Acta">Acta</option>
<option value="Especial">Caso Especial</option>
</select>
</p> 

<p><span class="separate" >Comentarios:</span>  
<textarea name="dm_comments" id="dm_comments"  class="text"  ></textarea></p>
<p><span class="separate" >Imagen:</span>  
<input type="file" name="dm_img" id="dm_img" value=""     /></p>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<button id="sendForm"> Enviar </button>
</div>
</div>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Errores encontrados..">
  <p> Falta información en los siguientes campos:
  <div id="listHere"></div>
  </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
HTML

sub trim($) {   

    my $string = shift;   
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;  
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;      
    return $string;    

}

exit(0);
```